# LibGDX spritebatch resize relative to screen size

Tags: java, libgdx

here is my problem. I'm trying to render a texture using LibGDX, with it's position and width relative to the screen size. Here's how I do it:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(logo.getKeyFrame(frame), (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) - (logo.getKeyFrame(frame).getRegionWidth() / 2), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - logo.getKeyFrame(frame).getRegionHeight());
    batch.end();

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}
```

The problem is, when I try to resize the window, the image doesn't get rendered where it should be. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe try making width and height variables and set them to their new value in `resize()`. Then use those variables to set the size of the image.

Comment: @vedi0boy I just tried and nothing changed.Should I be using getRegionWidth() to get the width of the image?

Comment: I use LibGDX a lot and I never ran into this issue because I use an `OrthographicCamera` with a `StretchViewport` and it works perfectly the way I showed you. If you are interested in knowing about that more, just tell me and I'll tell you how to set it up so that your screen will stretch perfectly on `resize()`.

Comment: Sounds like the viewport isn't doing what you expect so you either picked the wrong one or you misunderstand how it's supposed to behave.

Comment: I don;t think he is using a viewport or camera at all, besides the one for his stage of course but the spritebatch is not configured with anything though.

Comment: Since the OP calls stage.draw, the stage's viewport will be used (left over from the previous frame since it is never changed anywhere else). Assuming the stage is linked to the same sprite batch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I found a way to fix my problem. I call this in the resize method

```
    batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, width, height);
```